# remove domain names with specific extension from text in php but keep text

Tags: php, regex, url, str-replace

So 10,001 question about regex but i can't find anything related exactly to this, there are many regex questions so i understand if you think this is already answered but i can't find answer anywhere.

So i have website where user can post description about products but some users would want to post link to their products and i want to strip out domain names from text in description but keep text, i don't need any fancy thing that will completely remove everything, just to recognize when some word is used in pattern with domain extensions. So for example if user write text:

```
I am selling a mobile phone, visit my product page 
somewebsite.com/products?mobilephone=21 for more info and details.
```

I need to catch `somewebiste.com` phrase and remove it from text but submit rest of the text so in end it gets:

```
I am selling a mobile phone, visit my product page 
/products?mobilephone=21 for more info and details.
```

That would be enough for me, it's only matter that it catches domain name and remove it.

And since it's localized website i only need to add list of most used domain names like .com .net .org .info .ch .de ... and so on. And catch phrase even if user posted multiple links to product, so:

```
I am selling a mobile phone, visit my product page 
somewebsite.com/products?mobilephone=21 for more info 
and details. And if you want to see all mobile phones 
go to allphones.somewebsite.com
```

That would strip out both domain names and end up like this.

```
I am selling a mobile phone, visit my product page 
/products?mobilephone=21 for more info and details. 
And if you want to see all mobile phones go to 
allphones.
```

Some str_replace or regex could solve this ?

Comment: This worked thanks!